# How to get the user action like OK or Cancel on a javascript alert/confirmation box in C# or VB.Net Winform App?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, internet-explorer, alert

I am using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer APIs in my Vb.Net WinForms application to record user actions from Internet Explorer in my application.

By using "GetForegroundWindow" of "user32.dll" I can get the handle of the confirmation box. I can easily get the required information like its 'ClassName' and 'WindowText'.

Now I need to know the user action which closes the confirmation box i.e. user pressed OK or the Cancel button?

Here is the sample code which I am using

```
Private Function GetAlertMessage() As String
    Dim hwnd = GetForegroundWindow
    Dim ForeGroundWindowClassName As String = GetClassNameFromHandle(hwnd)

    If String.CompareOrdinal("#32770", ForeGroundWindowClassName) = 0 Then
        'Its definitely an alert
        Dim AlertMessage As String = String.Empty

        For Each childWin As WindowChildInfo In GetChildWindows(hwnd)
            If childWin.ClassName.ToLower = "static" Then
                AlertMessage = childWin.Text
            End If
        Next
        Return AlertMessage
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetClassNameFromHandle(ByVal hWnd As Integer) As String
    Dim sbClassName As New Text.StringBuilder("", 256)
    Call GetClassName(hWnd, sbClassName, 256)
    Return sbClassName.ToString
End Function

Private children As List(Of WindowChildInfo)
Public Function GetChildWindows(ByVal hwnd As Integer) As List(Of WindowChildInfo)
    children = New List(Of WindowChildInfo)
    EnumChildWindows(hwnd, AddressOf EnumProc, Nothing)
    Return children
End Function

Private Function EnumProc(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    If hwnd <> 0 Then
        children.Add(New WindowChildInfo(hwnd, GetClassNameFromHandle(hwnd), GetText(hwnd)))
    End If
    Return 1
End Function
```

Comment: In c# you can use  DialogResult class for this.

Comment: It's not a winform Dialog box, It is a javascript confirm box which is opened in separate running Internet Explorer.

Comment: You cannot do this. You'll need to handle JavaScript message boxes arising from the browser from code that runs in the browser. Enumerating the button control windows won't ever tell you which one was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question correctly than you need to use confirm in javascript.

```
var action= confirm("your message here");
```

This will return true if user press ok and false if user press cancel.

Comment: i think OP is trying to trap the MessageBoxResult from *outside* the browser, not from within the browser. he is using dot-net Winforms which surely is a desktop app separate from the browser itself.

Comment: @inquisitive: Yes you are absolutely right, 'Mairaj' solution is not going to work for me.